# How to run shell command through python lambda funciton?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda

I am trying to use maigret (python module) with python script through lambda function.

Below is the code i tested locally and it works fine:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    if event["network"] == "facebook":
        name = event["name"]
        output = subprocess.run("maigret warriors --site Facebook", shell=True, capture_output=True).stdout
        print(output) #prints the output as expected locally
```

But the same code in lambda function return empty output.

How can i use the maigret module through python script or how can i run shell command in python script?

Comment: Does anything shows up if you replace `stdout` with `stderr`?

Comment: @jvx8ss yes when i do stdout it prints b''. and. when i do stderr it prints "b'/bin/sh: maigret: command not found\n'"

Comment: This is probably happening because `maigret` is not in `PATH`

Comment: You could also use `/path/to/maigret warriors --site Facebook` instead

Comment: @jvx8ss when i did that  stderr was b'/bin/sh: /path/to/maigret: No such file or directory\n'

Comment: `/path/to` is just to demonstrate that its supposed to be the full path of the executable. you should replace it with `maigret` actual path

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. In the end a AWS Lambda is just a microVM running Amazon Linux. So running Bash scripts is possible.

But I would not recommend it. Before we go into what I would propose instead, I want to give you an overview of the two options you have if you absolutely have to run a Bash script.

### Option 1: Use custom runtime

AWS allows you to provide your own runtime (instead of using the default runtimes that AWS provides). This usually involves creating a Docker image or providing a custom runtime through the deployment package. You can find an example of this in the AWS documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-walkthrough.html

### Option 2: Run script from code

You could also just put the script in your deployment package and execute it in code:

Example in Python:

```py
import os

os.system('/path/to/script.sh')
```

### What you should do instead

But all of those options are not what you should do. I propose you find a package written in a language supported by Lambda natively to provide your use-case needs.